# #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

We have quite a few questions on incorrect mysql syntax, with almost the same question title.

I cannot figure out a way to get SO search to find the questions with this string in the title, but a little Google foo seems to work.
https://www.google.se/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+intitle:%22%231064+-You+have+an+error+in+your+SQL+syntax%22

Should they be closed as off topic -> simple typo? Should we give them a better title?

Comment: "*Should they be closed as off topic -> simple typo?*" - Yes.

Comment: [Related on the network-wide meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159317/close-as-too-localized-when-the-error-message-is-a-specific-and-exact-pointer-to) which I asked before it split from SO meta and when "Too Localized" was what was used for typo closures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%231064+%5Bsql%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano+wiki%3Ano and to make matters worse... there's a tag [mysql-error-1064]... which people aparently don't read just add heh

Comment: @MichaelDibbets wow, that tag is oddly specific.

Comment: I would be happy to devote my del votes for a while on the truly localized ones that the community consensus has agreement on. Would you like to start a list? A few of us were about to switch our focus to mysql today anyway.